# "Default" method for a Date object

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node REPL, I get the following:

```
> console.log(new Date())
2022-06-21T14:52:30.675Z
undefined
> console.log(new Date().toString())
Tue Jun 21 2022 14:52:36 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
undefined
```

In the first statement, what is the method that was invoked on the `Date` object, if any?

Comment: I think `console.log` automatically invokes `toString`, but it likely depends on the environment

Comment: I get a different output than you. In Firefox, the first output is a collapsible representation, the second is a string.

Comment: Probably `.toISOString`.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely [`Date.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

```js
console.log(new Date().toISOString())
console.log(new Date().toString())
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Yes, `let d = new Date(); console.log(d); console.log(d.toISOString());` produce the same output for my system.